# Decrease number of columns in textarea in mobile view

Tags: html

I want to Decrease number of columns in textarea in mobile view,how can I do this?
Here my HTML(based bootstrap):

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-2">
          <textarea name="content" rows="4" cols="80" id="content"></textarea>
     </div>
 </div>
```

In mobile view I need to Scroll the screen sideways to show all the texterea,so I want to decrease the number of columns.

Comment: Why don't you use height and width in place of rows and columns in your css so that you can decrease the size as you like in css?

Comment: can I do this with the classes of bootstraop?

Comment: You can use whatever you want with bootstrap. Create a CSS file include it after bootstrap.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the class `form-control` on the textarea and then control its width by setting the width on its parent. `form-control` essentially tries to cover full width of its parent. So when you set the parent's class as something like `col-xs-10` the textarea will be constrained accordingly.

If your screen width reduces, the textarea will resize automatically.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-10">
          <textarea class="form-control" name="content" rows="4" id="content"></textarea>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I remove the attr cols="80" and it influenced from the bootstrap classes.